# NSURLSessionでdelegateメソッドが呼ばれない

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

お世話になります
NSURLSessionで通信処理を書いているのですが、complecationHandlerを書いた時は、正しく呼ばれるのですが、delegateで処理しようトルするとうまくいかずに困っております。

```
let request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:xmlUrl)


            var config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

            self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: config,
                delegate: self,
                delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())


            func completionBlock(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void {
                if error != nil{

                    if self.initLoading{
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    }else{
                        self.footerIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                    self.isLoading = false
                    self.initLoading = false
                    self.nowLoading = false

                    //アラートを表示して終了

                    self.workview.reloadData()

                }else{
                    if !notParseFlag{
                        var parser : NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
                        parser.delegate = self
                        parser.parse()
                    }
                }

            }


            //var task:NSURLSessionDataTask = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            var task : NSURLSessionDataTask = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:completionBlock)
            task.resume()
```

だとうまくcomplecationBlcokに入ってきます

```
let request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:xmlUrl)


            var config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

            self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: config,
                delegate: self,
                delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

//                func completionBlock(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void {
//                    if error != nil{
//                        
//                        if self.initLoading{
//                            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
//                        }else{
//                            self.footerIndicator.stopAnimating()
//                        }
//                        self.isLoading = false
//                        self.initLoading = false
//                        self.nowLoading = false
//                        
//                        //アラートを表示して終了
//                        
//                        self.workview.reloadData()
//                        
//                    }else{
//                        if !notParseFlag{
//                            var parser : NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
//                            parser.delegate = self
//                            parser.parse()
//                        }
//                    }
//                    
//                }

```
            var task:NSURLSessionDataTask = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            //var task : NSURLSessionDataTask = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:completionBlock)
            task.resume()
```

以下delegateメソッド

```
                extension  WorkList {
                func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void){
                    println("request_start")
                }
                func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didBecomeDownloadTask downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask) {
                    println("............")

                }
                func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
                    println("request_finish")

                    if !notParseFlag{
                        var parser : NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
                        parser.delegate = self
                        parser.parse()
                    }
                }

                func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?){
                    if self.initLoading{
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    }else{
                        self.footerIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                    self.isLoading = false
                    self.initLoading = false
                    self.nowLoading = false

                    //アラートを表示して終了

                    self.workview.reloadData()

                }
                func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?){
                    println(error)
                }

                func cancelConnect(){
                    self.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler
                    {
                            (dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks) -> Void in

                            self.cancelTasksByUrl(dataTasks     as [NSURLSessionTask])

                    }
                }

                private func cancelTasksByUrl(tasks: [NSURLSessionTask])
                {
                    for task in tasks
                    {
                        task.cancel()
                    }
                }
            }
```

request_startがデバッグにあるのは確認したので、どうしたもんかなと。。。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決しました。
こちらを参照し、実装を以下のようにしました

```
      extension  WorkList {
      func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void){
          println("request_start")

          if response.isKindOfClass(NSHTTPURLResponse){
              let httpURLResponse:NSHTTPURLResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse

              let statuscode = httpURLResponse.statusCode
              println(statuscode)

              if statuscode == 200{
                  println("success")

                  let disposition:NSURLSessionResponseDisposition = NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow
                  completionHandler(disposition)
              }else{
                  println("statusinvalid")
                  handleError()
              }
          }


      }
      func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didBecomeDownloadTask downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask){
          println("didBecomeDownloadTask")
      }

      func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData){
          if !notParseFlag{
              var parser : NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
              parser.delegate = self
              parser.parse()
          }
      }

      func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?){
          println(error)
          if error != nil{
              println("didCompleteWithError")
              handleError()
          }


      }
      func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?){
          println(error)

          if error != nil{
              println("didBecomeInvalidWithError")
              handleError()
          }
      }

      func cancelConnect(){
          self.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler
          {
              (dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks) -> Void in

              self.cancelTasksByUrl(dataTasks     as [NSURLSessionTask])

          }
      }

      func handleError(){
          if self.initLoading{
              SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
          }else{
              self.footerIndicator.stopAnimating()
          }
          self.isLoading = false
          self.initLoading = false
          self.nowLoading = false

          //アラートを表示して終了
          showAlert()

          self.workview.reloadData()
      }

      private func cancelTasksByUrl(tasks: [NSURLSessionTask])
      {
          for task in tasks
          {
              task.cancel()
          }
      }
  }
```